# setting the value of other textfields to nil

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I am trying to have 6 textfields that requires only one textfield to be filled in order to calculate the value of the second textbox. however i would like the textbox that are empty and arent used to not display 0.00000 but instead remain empty. how can this be done?
thanks

Comment: You don't manage manually the display of the textbox ?

Answer (score 0):

We need more information - why do the text fields contain 0.000000 to start with?

Because the code to clear a text field is pretty simple I think we don't understand your question :)

```
[myTextField setText:@""];
```

Comment: when u solve for one unknwon it sets them all to zero, how can i restrict the fields for which it solves. i have 6 unknowns, i need 1 know to find one other unknwon, however i dont need the other fields to display nothing. yes i knw the setText method im currently using it ...